# jquery on reassigning an event

Tags: jquery

When you add an event handler using .on and namespacing, if you repeat that (add it again) - does it overwrite the existing handler or just add a second event handler?

For example:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)

$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
```

Is doing that bad? is it better to do:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
$('#myDiv').off('click.download', 'p')
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
```

Comment: have you tried it before asking?

Answer (score 1):

If you add multiple on's it appends them to the list of events performed.  The second form

```
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
$('#myDiv').off('click.download', 'p')
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
```

is the correct way to do something (as long as the two handlers are actually different)...  Actually to do

```
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler)
$('#myDiv').off('click.download', 'p', handler)
$('#myDiv').on('click.download', 'p', handler2)
```

is even better in case some other code added an event that you didn't want removed.